# Python ModuleNotFoundError when cloning Repository via SSH

Tags: python

I have cloned a repository using ssh and created a new branch. I want to import local modules from the parent directory, but always receive an ModuleNotFoundError.
I already tried adding the parent directory to the path list:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("./")
import testfile as test
```

Importing the desired module also throws the ModuleNotFoundError:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'testfile'
```

Is there something essential that Im missing here?

Comment: you should show the full exact error

Comment: @DanielFarrell sorry, just added the exact error message.

Comment: you can see from the error that the code you included is not related.  You need to look at the code that mentions `testfile`

Comment: @DanielFarrell I imported `testfile.py` with `import testfile as test`. Also Im able to navigate to the module through this import statement

Comment: This has nothing to do with Git or SSH (so I snipped both tags). The error means that `testfile` isn't on your python path (`sys.path`). If you wanted to insert the *parent* directory, that would be `../`, not `./`, so that's probably it right there.

Comment: @torek That did not work for me either. Im getting the same ModuleNotFoundError. Using                                                                            `import os, sys
os.chdir('src')
sys.path.append('.') ` works however.

Comment: Sounds like you don't want to insert either `./` *or* `../` into `sys.path`, but rather `src` (or, longer but maybe clearer to some, `./src`). Remember, though, that the *current working directory* when you run some Python program may be anywhere in your file system, not necessarily where the Python program was extracted into.

Comment: Doing relative imports like this is in general risky. The recommended way to deal with multiple Python versions, path-relative installations, and other such vagaries is to use the virtual environment stuff. Activating a virtual environment sets up the PYTHONPATH variable so that `sys.path` is set correctly at startup, and you can simply import things from now-well-defined locations, with known packages all pre-installed via `pip` or `pip3` as appropriate.